# HTTP Compression - which technique is best for security and performance?

Tags: http, compression

We have 3 HTTP Compression available in IIS 7.0

- GZIP Encoding
- DEFLATE Encoding
- BZIP2 Encoding

What are the difference between these three? Which is the **best compression for security and performance**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gzip and deflate both use the deflate algorithm, but gzip adds a few bytes in headers. bzip2 gives better compression, but is much slower.

Security has nothing to do with it as the compression needs to be reversible. If security is an issue your best bet is to use HTTPS.

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I elaborated on why security is nothing to do with compression.

Answer (score 0):

There is no “best” compression. All algorithms have different properties, such as compression/decompression speed, memory consumption while compressing/decompressing, or compression ratio. It all depends on *your* requirements. Nobody can tell you what is best for *you* (unless you tell us a lot more about your requirements).